# What does the "template" keyword mean when places after scope resolution operator (::)

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I came accross the following construct while reading this [article](http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/13/tiny-metaprogramming-library/):

```
template<typename F, typename...As>
using meta_apply = typename F::template apply<As...>;
```

Can someone explain to me what does the `template` keyword mean when it's placed after the scope resolution operator `::`? Or better point me to where this usage is described in C++ reference of any kind. I tried looking it up myself but couldn't find any.

**EDIT**

Consider also this code from the same  [article](http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/13/tiny-metaprogramming-library/):

```
meta_compose<F0, meta_compose<F1, F2>::template apply>::template apply
```

Here, the last `apply` token is *not* followed either `<` or `>` thus its usage is not explained in either of the two alternative questions suggested.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, please see my edit

Comment: It tells the compiler that the thing afterwards names a template, so that 1) it knows how to parse `<` and 2) it knows that said thing can be used as a template argument for a template template parameter.

Comment: In other words to be able to bind it `template<class> class F0` template argument above (in the article)? - I think you answered my question.